# How to Resolve CORS Issues in a React Application?

Tags: cors, issue-tracking

I'm currently working on a React application, and I've encountered CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issues when trying to make API requests to a different domain. I've tried various solutions found online, but none seem to work for my specific case. Can someone provide a step-by-step guide or suggest a reliable method to resolve CORS problems in a React project? Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

want a detailed and perfect answer

Answer (score 1):

You can not do anything on frontend if your server is not allowing requests from your domain. On backend you should whitelist the domain your work on. For this you can create dev environment and whitelist localhost.